# Usar varias etiquetas en {%if%}

Tags: liquid

Les comento, estoy creando un ecommerce con Liquid en la pataforma de Shopify.
Necesito mostrar le precio para un tipo de usuario que esta definido por etiquetaas.

La llave se usa asi {%if customer.tag.contains 'B2B'%}
Necesito saber como usar varias etiquetas.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Has probado `{%if customer.tag.contains 'B2B' or customer.tag.contains 'XXX' or customer.tag.contains 'YYY' %}`?

Comment: Gracias, lo probare de esta manera. Eh hecho lo mismo pero remplazando "or" por "," y no funcionaba, quizas asi si funcione..

Comment: Si ah funcionado! Muchas gracias men!!! eh creado una llave larguisima jaja pero en fin, funcional.. .